# How to slide up to both hide and show divs using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a school project for which I need to make a website.
For this website I want the first div to slide up and hide, after which the second div to slide up and show.
I've spent a few hours looking online but I either couldn't find a working solution or a solution that only worked partially.

this is the code I currently have for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#next1").click(function() {
    $("#1").slideUp("slow", function() {
      $("#2").slideDown("slow");
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#next2").click(function() {
    $("#2").slideUp("slow", function() {
      $("#1").slideDown("slow");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Project Pie</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="1">


    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:hotpink; border: none;">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:white; border: none">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, est.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, error?</p>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Number People:</label>
          <input type="number">
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, corporis?</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, itaque?</p>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Number layers:</label>
          <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:hotpink; border: none">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="next1">next</button>
  </div>

  <div id="2" style="display:none;">


    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:gold; border: none">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:white; border:none">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, est.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, error?</p>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Number People:</label>
          <input type="number">
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, corporis?</p>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, itaque?</p>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Number Layers:</label>
          <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:gold; border: none;">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="next2">next</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope someone can help me find a working solution.

Comment: what do you mean by it's "partially" working?

Comment: I am a bit confused to what it is you want - you want the yellow div to slide up and the pink div to slide down..? As I can see it, it does exactly that

Comment: @RachelGallen partially might not have been the correct word. what I found reverses the direction. so it did make div2 show by sliding up but it hid div1 by sliding it down, which isn't what I want.

Comment: @Lasse I want both divs to slide up, the one already visible sliding up to hide, and the one hidden to slide up to reveal itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **slideUp** - Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.
>
> **slideDown** - Display the matched elements with a sliding motion.

So `slideUp` while show is not possible. `animate()` can be used to achieve this effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#next1").click(function() {
    $("#1").slideUp("slow", function() {
      slideUp($("#2"));
    });
  });

  $("#next2").click(function() {
    $("#2").slideUp("slow", function() {
      slideUp($("#1"));
    });
  });
});

function slideUp($ele) {
  var height = $ele.height() + 'px';
  $ele.css({
    'margin-top': height,
    'height': height,
    'overflow': 'hide'
  }).show().animate({
    'marginTop': '0px',
    'height': 'unset',
    'overflow': 'unset'
  }, 400);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Project Pie</h1>
</div>

<div id="1">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:hotpink; border: none;">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:white; border: none">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, est.</p>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, error?</p>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Number People:</label>
        <input type="number">
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, corporis?</p>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, itaque?</p>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Number layers:</label>
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:hotpink; border: none">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="next1">next</button>
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:gold; border: none">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color:white; border:none">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, est.</p>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, error?</p>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Number People:</label>
        <input type="number">
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, corporis?</p>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, itaque?</p>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Number Layers:</label>
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:gold; border: none;">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="next2">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. with this I can most likely make it work

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, and this code should do the trick:

```js
function slideUp(elementId) {
  var div = $(elementId);
  var height = div.css({
    display: "block"
  }).height();

  div.css({
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginTop: height,
    height: 0
  }).animate({
    marginTop: 0,
    height: height
  }, 500, function() {
    $(this).css({
      display: "",
      overflow: "",
      height: "",
      marginTop: ""
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#next1").click(function() {
    $("#1").slideUp("slow", function() {
      slideUp("#2");
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#next2").click(function() {
    $("#2").slideUp("slow", function() {
      slideUp("#1");
    });
  });
});
```